# With which method I can manipulate the duration of intervals

Tags: manipulation-detection

My stimuli include auditory time intervals both in the form of single durations or sequences of intervals. To be precise  I will use a discrimination task and participants are going to listen to the first stimulus and then hear another stimulus which is either the same or different from the first one. I case the second stimulus is different what would be a good method to manipulate the duration (making it longer or shorter)? Some investigators use methods like the staircase (and other things) to structurally manipulate the durations based on the participants' response (making it harder if the answer is correct or making is easier if the answer is incorrect). I'm just wondering what are the statistical methods for this purpose?

Comment: This looks more like a psychology question than a statistical one although it is not absolutely clear to me. Can you edit to clarify just what you need?

Comment: I edited my question trying to make it more clear.